# how to add objects extracted from a database to an arraylist?

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

i wrote a simple program extracting some data from a database, each line from the table of the database is structured in an object that i create using a normal constructor, then i add that object to my arraylist using the .add() method.
my problem is that when i outprint what my arraylist contains i find all the cases containing only the last line from the database!! i tried to print while adding to the arraylist, i found out that each time i add a new object it gets in the new and the old case of the arraylist, so the last object (which represents the last line of the database's table) gets in all the arraylist!
so any help plz?

here are my two classes:
**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
    public static String nom, prenom, adrs;
    private static int id, maxcredit, totalpaye, totalnonpaye;

    //i want data to be stored in this arraylist
    public static ArrayList<ClientInfo> clients =  new ArrayList();

public Client(){    
    connectDB();//connecting to the database
    getClients();//storing the data from the database to arraylist!!
}

private static Connection conn = null;
private static Statement stmt = null;
private static ResultSet rs = null;

private static final String Conn_string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/carnetcredit";



//Connect to DB:
public static void connectDB(){
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Conn_string, "root", "");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

//Get all clients list:
public static void getClients(){
    try{

        stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from client");

        System.out.println("Table Client : ");

        while (rs.next()){

            //getting data from database to simpte variables
            id = rs.getInt("idclient");
            nom = rs.getString(2);
            prenom = rs.getString(3);
            adrs = rs.getString(4);
            maxcredit = rs.getInt(5);
            totalpaye = rs.getInt(6);
            totalnonpaye = rs.getInt(7);

            //creating an object using the data extracted from the database
            ClientInfo client = new ClientInfo(id,nom,prenom,adrs,maxcredit,totalpaye,totalnonpaye);

            //adding the object to the arraylist
            clients.add(client);

    }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }

}


//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Main Method :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
public static void main(String[] args) {

    conn = null;
    stmt = null;
    rs = null;


    ClientInfo client = new ClientInfo();
    new Client();
    int i = 0;
    while (i<clients.size()){
        client = clients.get(i);
        System.out.println("id : "+ client.id +" - nom : "+client.nom+" - prenom : "+client.prenom+" - adresse : "+client.adrs+
                " - maxcredit : "+client.maxcredit+" - total payé : "+client.totalpaye+" - total non payé : "+client.totalnonpaye);
        i++;
    }
}
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

}
```

**ClientInfo.java**

```
public class ClientInfo {

    public  String nom, prenom, adrs;
    public  int id, maxcredit, totalpaye, totalnonpaye;


public ClientInfo(){
    id = 0;
    nom = prenom = adrs = "";
    maxcredit = totalpaye = totalnonpaye = 0;
}

public ClientInfo(int id, String nom, String prenom, String adrs, int maxcredit, int totalpaye,int totalnonpaye){
    this.id = id;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.adrs = adrs ;
    this.maxcredit = maxcredit ;
    this.totalpaye = totalpaye ;
    this.totalnonpaye = totalnonpaye;

}


  }
```

thanks guys!!

Comment: You should in the cycle create a new variable but don't use the same for other data

Comment: can you indicate exactly what variable you're talking about please? and if you can write me a line of code, it would be appreciated! thnx!! and i guess you should answer in the answer section not the comments ! thanks again. - @VasylLyashkevych

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I see

*containing only the last line from the database*

I automatically know that this is caused by static variables.

change

```
public static String nom, prenom, adrs;
private static int id, maxcredit, totalpaye, totalnonpaye;
```

to be non-static